# Удаление из файла строки

Tags: javafx

Есть программа, в ней нужна функция удаления из файла строки с нулевым количеством товара, у меня она удаляет эти строки из таблицы, но как удалить ее еще и из файла?

```
public class W2Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchorPane;
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private Button button1;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem openFile;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem closeFile;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem removeGoods;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Goods, String> codeGoods;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Goods, String> nameGoods;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Goods, Integer> priceGoods;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Goods, Integer> quantityGoods;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Goods> tableView;
    @FXML
    private TextField textField;
    @FXML
    private TextField textField1;
    @FXML
    private TextField textField2;

    private File fileGoods;
    private BufferedReader bufreader;
    private List<String[]> goodsList;
    private ObservableList<Goods> data;

    public void loadFileGoods(){ //чтение файла

        String brsl = null;
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Выбор файла данных");
        Stage stage = (Stage)anchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TXT", "*.txt"));
        fileGoods = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
        if(fileGoods!=null){
            System.out.println(fileGoods.getAbsolutePath());
            try{
                bufreader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileGoods.getAbsolutePath()));
                goodsList.clear();
                while((brsl = bufreader.readLine())!=null){
                    String[] sarrl = brsl.split(";");
                    if(sarrl.length == Constants.NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS){
                        goodsList.add(sarrl);
                    } else{
                        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
                    }
                }
                loadShowViewTable();
                textField.setDisable(false);
                button1.setDisable(false);
                bufreader.close();                
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                System.out.println("Смотри файл данных - недостаточно данных");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println("Смотри файл данных - не удалось преобразовать текст в число");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }        
    }

    @FXML
    void loadShowViewTable() throws NumberFormatException{ //показать таблицу
        data.clear();
        for(String[] el: goodsList){
           data.add(new Goods(
                    el[0],
                    el[1], 
                    Integer.parseInt(el[2]), 
                    Integer.parseInt(el[3])));
        }
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        codeGoods.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Goods,String>("codeGoods"));
        nameGoods.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Goods,String>("nameGoods"));       
        priceGoods.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Goods, Integer>("priceGoods"));
        quantityGoods.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Goods, Integer>("quantityGoods"));
        tableView.setItems(data);

    }

    @FXML
    void listDelete() throws IOException{
        List<String[]> goodsDeleteList = new LinkedList<String[]>();
         for(String[]el:goodsList){
             if(!el[2].equals("0")){
                 goodsDeleteList.add(el);
             }
         }
         goodsList.clear();
         goodsList = goodsDeleteList;
         loadShowViewTable();

    }

    @FXML
    void changeList() {
        List<String[]> goodsChangeList = new LinkedList<String[]>();
         for(String[]el:goodsList){
             if (el[0].equals(textField.getText())) {
                if (!textField1.getText().equals(""))
                    el[2] = textField1.getText();
                if (!textField2.getText().equals(""))
                    el[3] = textField2.getText();
             }
             goodsChangeList.add(el);
         }
         goodsList.clear();
         goodsList = goodsChangeList;
         loadShowViewTable();
    }

    public void openFile(){
        loadShowViewTable();
    }
    public void closeFile(){
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public void update1(){
       String strUpdate1 = textField.getText();

    }
    public void changeButton() {
        changeList();
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
       data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        goodsList = new LinkedList<String[]>();
    }  

    @FXML
    void listDelete() throws IOException {

        List<String[]> goodsDeleteList = new LinkedList<String[]>();
         for(String[]el:goodsList){
             if(!el[2].equals("0")){
                 goodsDeleteList.add(el);
             }
         }
         goodsList.clear();
         goodsList = goodsDeleteList;
         loadShowViewTable();
         try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileGoods.getAbsolutePath(), 
    false)){
             String str;
             int count = 0, i = 0;
         for(String[]el:goodsList){
                 if(count != 0){
                    writer.write(el[i]);
                    writer.write(";");
                    count++;
                    i++;
                 } else {
                     count = 0;
                     writer.write(el[i]);
                     writer.write("\n");
                     i++;
                 }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        } 

   }
```

Пытался сделать нечто подобное, но не получилось :(

Пример того, как выглядит текстовый файл:

> 1;pencil;0;30
>
> 2;package;25;50
>
> 4;list;10;35
>
> 5;book;100;80
>
> 6;pen;308;22
>
> 7;bag;55;300
>
> 8;album;45;90
>
> 9;magnit;150;30
>
> 10;netbook;100;100

[image: Пример внешнего вида программы]

Comment: `List<String[]> goodsList` - зачем хранить лист массивов строк, если можно хранить лист объектов класса `Goods`?

Comment: `int count = 0` всегда будет равен `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как это вижу я:

```
@FXML
void listDelete() throws IOException {

    List<String[]> goodsDeleteList = new ArrayList<>();

     for(String[] good : goodsList){
         if(!good[2].equals("0")){
             goodsDeleteList.add(good);
         }
     }

     goodsList = goodsDeleteList;

     loadShowViewTable();

     fileGoods.delete();
     try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileGoods, true)){

         for(String[] el: goodsList) {
             writer.append(String.join(";", el));
             writer.append("\n");
         }

     } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
     } 

}
```

P.S. Написал под Ваш код. Я бы все иначе сделал бы.

Comment: Файл записывается в 1 строчку, а не построчно, но все равно программа его считывает, поэтому спасибо огромное. Нас не обучали джаве, но курсач попросили переделать под нее, поэтому код плоховат :)

Comment: @ReFeSeR обновил ответ.